# sorting of Dates in vb

Tags: vb.net, list

i have several file names in the form of Dates(DD-MM-YYYY). i have read all the name and sort it . But if the day is more than 12, the  application terminates . i stuck in this part .

enter code here

```
For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath)
Dim name = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
MsgBox(name)
list.Add(name)
Next
list.Sort(New Comparison(Of Date)(Function(x As Date, y As Date) y.CompareTo(x)))
ComboBox1.DataSource = list
```

and i did another process

```
 Dim Dates As List(Of Date)
 For Each cbItem As Date In Me.ComboBox1.Items
 Dates = {
       Date.Parse(cbItem.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        }.ToList
 Dates.Sort(New Comparison(Of Date)(Function(x As Date, y As Date) y.CompareTo(x)))
 Next
 ComboBox2.DataSource = Dates
```

Comment: Use DateTime.ParseExact to specify the expected date format.

Comment: i tired ..can i show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim name As String
Dim list As List(of DateTime) = new List(of DateTime)
For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath)
    name = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
    list.Add(Datetime.ParseExact(name, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
Next
list.Sort(New Comparison(Of Date)(Function(x As Date, y As Date) y.CompareTo(x)))
ComboBox1.DataSource = list
```

Note: I've declared the list as a list of `DateTime` and converted the file name from `String` to `DateTime` inside the `Add` using `DateTime.ParseExact` method.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up your datetime format.

First you say you have the format `DD-MM-YYYY`, but later in the code you try to parse them as `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Also, the fact that you get an exception once you hit a day > 12 indicates that you are trying to parse the day as month, since there are only 12 month in a year.

Comment: if i did like this also  DD-MM-YYYY they are not coming

Comment: Why to you call `Dates = {
       Date.Parse(cbItem.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        }.ToList` if the items already seem to be sorted?

Comment: What does sorted in date in month mean?

Comment: all the dates are sorted...like all dates of january, then all dates of february..then march